# How to return values from a object matched by a array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for the shortest way to get a new object as result from a existing object which matched all parts of a array.

Let me show what I mean:

```
This is the main-object
var mainobject={val1:text,val2:text,val3:text,val4:text,val5:text....};
```

now I want to get some of this entries like this

```
var only_some= get/function/what_i_need mainobject('val1','val3');

this will produce a new object with the matched parts from the mainobject

only_some.va1 = text
only_some.va3 = text
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There is no jQuery in this question, only Javascript. Please post the code you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: i'm a newbie in jquery/javascript, so i have no could, i only could write a each loop, but i think there should be a faster/better/easier way

Comment: @mikeDI have used easy way to resolve this..check my answer

Comment: Faster and easier to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them like this, using the rest operator for arguments

```js
var mainobject = {
  val1: 'text1',
  val2: 'text2',
  val3: 'text3',
  val4: 'text4',
  val5: 'text5'
};

function a(...args) {
var obj={};
  args.forEach((e) => {
  obj[e]=mainobject[e];
  })
  return obj;
}

console.log(a('val1', 'val4'));
```

Comment: great, but sorry, what is "args"? if i want to return the values as a new object,  - if i need to change the code to "args.forEach((e) =>return mainobject[e])"?

Comment: args is just a placeholder. The main thing is the ...  It will take all the arguments you provide in the function call and store in an array called args. You can iterate it over and get values.

Comment: Fore returning an object i have made edits. Check them

Answer (score 0):

```js
mainobject = {
  val1: "text1",
  val2: "text2",
  val3: "text3",
  val4: "text4",
  val5: "text5"
};



function searchObj(value1, value2) {
  var resultObj = {};
  for (var key in mainobject) {
    if (key == value1) {
      resultObj[value1] = mainobject[key];
    }
    if (key == value2) {
      resultObj[value2] = mainobject[key];
    }

  }
  return resultObj;
}
var only_some = searchObj("val1", "val3")
console.log("result", only_some)
console.log("result", only_some["val1"])
console.log("result", only_some["val3"])
```